Karaf Container failure killed 65 (line 177)
Karaf container is getting killed 65 while booting up
We tried below approaches for resolution but not successful:
Nodes restart.
Old yaml apply
Java and Env Parameter tried.
command: ["sh", "-c", "exec /deployments/bin/karaf"]
    env:

    - name: JAVA_OPTS

      value: "-Dkaraf.restart.jvm=false"

    - name: KARAF_EXEC

      value: "exec"

Sleep addition.
Liveliness/Readiness stop
Spawn cleaning script added.
Old Image applied.
Selfcare Namespace apply pod
